# Deeper Explanation of Prolog Count

Tags: prolog

Currently playing around in Prolog... I'm having trouble groking the count list rule. I haven't been able to find a good explanation anywhere. Can someone give me a break down of it at each recursion?

```
count(0, []).
count(Count, [Head|Tail]) :-
    count(TailCount, Tail),
    Count is TailCount + 1.
```

One place says that it is recursive (which makes sense to me) and another that says it isn't.

Comment: Try issuing `trace.`, then `count(N, [1,2,3]).` to see what the predicate does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure it's recursive, but not *tail* recursive. Writing *tail recursive* procedures is an optimization that allows the system to transform recursion into iteration, avoiding  useless stack usage for deterministics computations (like the one we are speaking of).
In this case (that BTW it's the same of the builtin length/2, just with arguments swapped), we can use an *accumulator*, and rewrite the procedure in this way:

```
count(C, L) :- count(0, C, L).

count(Total, Total, []).
count(SoFar, Count, [_Head|Tail]) :-
    Count1 is SoFar + 1,
    count(Count1, Count, Tail).
```

Some system older required a cut before the recursive call, to make the optimization effective:

```
    ...,
    !, count(Count1, Count, Tail).
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the inference rule is recursive.
This program tries to count the quantity of elements inside the list.

`count(0, []).` This is an axiom, a fact, something that its true because you said so. Here you are stating that every empty list has a count of zero.

`count(Count, [Head|Tail]) :-
    count(TailCount, Tail),
    Count is TailCount + 1.`

This is an inference rule, that it a rule that dictates that the left part of `:-` is true if the right part is true. This inference rule also uses pattern matching, wicth matchs non empty lists (`[Head|Tail]`).
Specifically, the count rule says that the `Count` variable of a non empty list is the count of the `Tail` part of the list, plus 1 (the plus 1 is for counting the Head element of the list).

Comment: I see that TailCount is the unknown, how does Prolog increment it such that it satisfies both terms of the rule? Is it similar to lazy evaluation or does it increment over each recursion?

Comment: TailCount is the same unknown variable as Count, except that it is applied to a smaller list in each recursion. Eventually, it reach the empty list, for which a result is known (zero), then backtracks with the known TailConut value adding 1 to satisfy the inference rule.